# How to determine a function of 2 variables from its derivative?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Please even the slightest advice would help!

If I have a function $V$ made of 2 variables $x_1$ and $x_2$, 
 and its derivative $$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{dV}{dx_1}\frac{dx_1}{dt} + \frac{dV}{dx_2}\frac{dx_2}{dt},$$ 
 how do I find $V$? I don't know how to integrate $dV/dt$. Both $dx_1/dt$ and $dx_2/dt$ are given.

Here is an example:
 $$dx_1/dt = -10x_2$$
 $$dx2/dt = 2x_1 - 20x_2 $$
 $$dV/dt = -2x_1^2 - 2x_1x_2 - x_2^2$$
 What is $V$?

Comment: oh and it's a lyapunov function in case anyone knows what that is, not that it really matters

Comment: there could be several $V$'s , are you looking for a specific $V$ ? do you want to solve the example you gave?

Comment: Yes that would be great if you could solve it! I'm getting something similar to this in the test tomorrow. And as far as I can tell the 2x2 matrix P where V=(x1  x2)P(x1  x2) has to be a symmetric matrix, I think that means there can be only one V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start you can make the following substitutions to find $x_1$ and $x_2$ :
from second equation we got : $x_1=1/2(dx_2/dt)+10x_2$ now differentiate $x_1$ with respect to 
$t$ : $dx_1/dt=1/2(d^2x_2/dt^2) + 10dx_2/dt$ now putting it in the first equation you have a 
differential equation in one variable. $10x_2=-1/2(d^2x_2/dt)-10dx_2/dt$ this is a simple diff. equation that you can solve with the approach: $a\exp(\lambda t)$. From here on the problem gets a bit simpler...

Comment: Wait, how do you solve that 2nd order diff equation? What are a and λ?

Comment: didn't you have an introduction to differential equations in your class? you should write in your question wich topic you are working at and at least wich  basic knowledge you have of it.

Comment: The only method I can remember precisely for 2nd order diff equations is Laplace, and we are not given an inverse laplace table in the test. What other method is there to use? I just need you to jog my memory of any other method. I know many.

Comment: I'm not a specialist so i don't want to confuse you with my knowledge if you didn't have the same methods in your class. Anyway if you want to understand what i mean with "ansatz : $a\exp(\lambda t)$" take a look at this:http://www.kostic.niu.edu/555/Ordinary%20Differential%20Equations-App-A.pdf . Look at the section "Linear equations with constant coefficients".

Comment: Well yes that's the original method I first took, but λ1 and λ2 were called r1 and r2, I remember it now. Thank you.